# Render single webpage as a subdomain

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress

Currently I have a wordpress website. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Render webpage https://example.com/specific-page/ as https://specific.example.com
```

This is what I have tried in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specific-page/
RewriteRule ^specific-page/(.*) https://specific.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

...which achieves the redirect but the page does not render.

Thank you in advance for your help, ServerFault!

Edit: *Since I cannot comment*

In this post when I say "render" I mean I would like the subdomain specific.example.com to show the contents of example.com/specific-page.

Comment: What does "the page does not render" mean? Exactly what is happening?

Comment: Does it "render" if you request `https://specific.example.com` directly? The redirect directive you posted does not perform the redirect quite as stated in your example, however, it should work in this specific example. But what do you actually mean by "Render a single webpage as a subdomain"? Are you simply wanting to redirect?

Comment: "since I can't comment" - You can't comment because you've logged in/registered as a different user than the one that posted the question. Consequently, you can't freely edit your question or receive notifications when other users comment/answer.

Comment: In order to answer this we would also need to know where the subdomain and main domain point to on the filesystem - how do they relate to each other. Do you have access to the server config?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a virtual host with the /var/www/html/example.com/specific-page/ folder as the DocumentRoot and have your DNS provider set up an A-record for https://specific.example.com